# Is it possible to add FQDN to Server behind NAT or to a NAT itself?

Tags: domain-name-system, nat, fqdn

I have multiple identical servers behind a NAT. I use the same IP and just change up the port to move between the server via port forwarding.The issue is that i am using self-signed certificates and getting the not secured warring.

Lets encrypt wont issue certificates as they only issue them for FQDNs.

is it possible to apply a domain name to a NAT or servers behind a NAT so that i can be issues a certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a domain name pointing to your public IP.   Lets encrypt will issue a certificate for the web server listening on the standard ports.  If you want to use that certificate for other application on other servers, you can copy the key and certificate to those servers.  If the web server handles multiple domains, you can get a multii-domain certificate.

You will need to upgrade the certificates periodically.

If you are using the applications for private use, you can set up your own certificate authority with a tool like tinyCA.  If you import the certificate authoritiy's certificate into your browser as a trusted certificate authority, you won't be prompted about invalid certificates.  (You may want your own CA for your VPN, if you run one.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Get a domain pointing to your public IP address, get a cert for this domain and that's it.

Browsers (or other apps) usually won't care if they connect to e.g `https://example.com:444` instead of port 443.

Comment: Will Lets Encrypt care about multiple certificates?

Comment: You do not need multiple certificates. Get one issued for  `service.example.com`  and use that one cert on all your back ends.